# Nake number of synchronous ajax calls in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there some way to make a number of synchronous ajax call in the same time? Lets say I have a number of ajax calls that have no dependency of each other. I want them to run in the same time but I can't use asynchronous calls because of some reason.

Comment: Make a bunch of synchronous calls asynchronously, funny :D

Comment: you can keep each next Ajax call in the success of previous call and so on

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan , But he wants multithreading of AjAx calls .

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan Yes, but that would be one after the other, not the same time. The question is a perfect example of an oxymoron.

Comment: This question is totally vague and a waste of time.

Comment: What is the "some reason" you can't do asynchronous? Wpould help answer the question

Comment: as i know closures is the only option which is also an abstraction of a call after an other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want - is to make the ajax calls in parallel and then make another action.

So you need to use the Async operations in parallel option - sync.js

Async operations in parallel -

http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html

```
var sync = require('synchronize')

function read(a, cb) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    cb(null, a)
  }, 1000)
}

// Runs in parallel
sync.fiber(function() {
  sync.parallel(function() {
    // You must call defer() manually within
    // a parallel operation.
    read(1, sync.defer())
    read(2, sync.defer())
  });
  var results = sync.await()
  // results now contains [1,2]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. Either you run them synchronously, one after another, or asynchronously, all at the same time :) What you want is absolute opposite and it can't be done, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use asynchronous calls. And do some kind of check to see if they've all been completed before doing what your script needs to do next, if that is the concern here. For example by using a `setTimeout()` function, or by using a global counter variable that is incremented with each ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't call it asynchronously but you can try using Web Workers instead

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp